# how can i get back the changes made to a select field with jinja\wtform

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I discover python 3 days ago, jinja/wtform yesterday. is very easy to understand,but I have some problems.

I´m traying to do a simple web application to allow users to change some configurations in a file. this file is for use in other application.

I need to show the choices in form of a DropDownList, and for this, I first read the file with all the choises (named 'config.ini') and show a page with all the options and a button tu submit the changes and save it in the same 'config.ini' file, with the same format.

I want to do this with a plain text file, not with alchemy or whatever db. just text. I dont need sessions, login form, nothing. is a single user system running a very slow resource computer. (raspberry)

my "config.ini" file look like this:

```
choice_1 alpha alpha betha gamma
choice_2 3 1 2 3
choice_3 red blue yellow red white black
```

first word is a choice name, second is a selected/default choice, them all other are a list of possible options for choice.

here my view.py:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
from app import app
from wtforms import SelectField, SubmitField
from flask_wtf import Form


class ConfigForm(Form):
    choice_1= SelectField('choice_1')
    choice_2= SelectField('choice_2')
    choice_3= SelectField('choice_3')
    submit = SubmitField('SaveChanges')

variables = []

@app.route('/')


@app.route('/index', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = ConfigForm()
    myconfigfile = {'name':'config.ini'}      

    if form.is_submitted():
            savefileid = open('config.ini','w')

            for variable in variables:
                    savefileid.write(variable['_name']+ ' ')
                    savefileid.write( variable['_value']+ ' ')

                    for option in variable['_options']:
                            savefileid.write(option + ' ')

                    savefileid.write("\n")

            savefileid.close()
    else:
            readfileid = open('config.ini')                                                         

            lineas = readfileid.readlines()                                                         
            for linea in lineas:                                                                    
                    mystrings = linea.split()                                                       
                    myset = set( mystrings [2:] )                                                   
                    mydict = dict({'_name':mystrings[0], '_value':mystrings [1], '_options':myset})  
                    variables.append(mydict)                                                        


            readfileid.close()                                                                      


    return render_template('index.html',                                                            
                    title='Home',
                    myconfigfile=myconfigfile,
                    variables=variables,
                    form=form
                    )
```

this other is my "index.hmtl" file.

```
<!-- extend base layout -->
{% extends "base.html" %}

<!-- {% from "_formhelper.html" import render_field %} -->

{% block content %}

<h1>Archivo: {{ myconfigfile.name }}</h1>

<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post">
<div style="width:300; height:300">

<table style="width:300px; height:300">
<tr>
    <td align="center"><strong>Choice</strong></th>
    <td align="center"><strong>value</strong></th>
</tr>

{% for avar in variables %}
<tr>
    <td width=120 align="left"><b>{{ avar._name }}</b></td>
    <td width=100 ><select name="{{ avar._name }}">

    {% for opcion in avar.opciones %}
            {% if opcion == avar._value %}
                    <option value="{{ avar._name }}" selected> {{ opcion }}</option>
            {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ avar._name }}"> {{ opcion }}</option>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}


    </select></td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}

</table>
</div>

    {{ form.submit }}

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

this other is my layout "base.html"

```
<html>
  <head>
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }} - Configuration</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Configuration</title>
    {% endif %}

</head>
  <body>
    <div>Configuração : <a href="/index">configuration parameters</a></div>
    <hr>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if messages %}
    <ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{ message }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        <hr>
        <p></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

my question is, how can i do this? how can I set my form allowing to change it, and them, when click on submit button, get back the changes to be saved back in the config file.

excuse my english, and thanks in advance.